# Algebraic Extension (Infinite)

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

If $E$ is an algebraic extension of the infinite field $F$,

show that $|E|=|F|$.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

The cardinal of an algebraic extension of a field $F$ is less or equal to the cardinal of the polynomials $F[X]$ over that field. And the cardinal of $F[X]$ is equal to the one of $$\bigcup_{k=0}^\infty F^n.$$

The cardinal of the set above is equal to the one of $F$ as $F$ is infinite (for all $n$ integer $\vert F^n \vert = \vert F \vert$). So $\vert E \vert \le \vert F \vert$. The converse inequality is obvious as $F \subset E$.